# unreal engine source code on github 404 error page not found

Tags: github, unreal-engine4

I'd like to get the unreal engine source code from GitHub. I successfully created an epic games account and connected it with my GitHub account. After that, I clicked the link of unreal engine on GitHub.

[image: unreal engine one GitHub]

But I encountered page error 404, page not found.
I googled and some said that after you connected your epic games account with your GitHub account, you would receive an email which contained the link to the code. Unfortunately, I just found that my GitHub email address was not verified and undeliverable. Maybe that's the reason why I did not receive the email. After that I added a new email address to my GitHub and verified it. But how can I receive the email now? I tried disconnecting the GitHub account and connecting the GitHub account again, but it did not work. I mean I cannot receive the email that contains the link. Or is there any other way I can get the link?

Comment: Are you sure you can't access it via https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine?

Comment: @lan A.B. King No, I can not. It says that "This is not the web page you are looking for".

Comment: That's because either you're not logged in to Github or you're not a member of EpicGames on Github. Here's a walkthrough on how to join the team: https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/ue4-on-github

Comment: @lan A.B. King This page is exactly what I'm following. I've logged into GitHub. Since I've linked my epic games account to my GitHub account, I think I'm given the access to the code. But the link is unaccessible.

Comment: +1 I am receiving the same issue. Followed all those steps, still receiving the same 404. Tried on multiple devices too

Comment: I have had the same issue eventhough i followed the instructions. Finally, i downloaded the 4.18 version from this github repo : https://github.com/soxueren/EpicGames-UnrealEngine . Had to create a symbolic link to a file which was missing, but then everything went well.

Answer (score 2):

You've got to [link your EpicGames account with your GitHub account](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/ue4-on-github) first:

[image]

Then you will receive an e-mail with a button:

[image]

after you click it, the repository will be available